# Python ''.format(): "tuple index out of range"?

Tags: python, string, formatting

Consider the following snippet:

```
>>> def foo(port, out, udp=False, ipv6=False, data=''):
...     if not data:
...             data = 'foo {family} {:port} {direction}'.format(
...                             family=('ipv6' if ipv6 else 'ipv4'),
...                             port=port,
...                             direction=('out' if out else 'in'))
...     return data
...
>>> foo(12345, out=True)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 6, in foo
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

As far as I know, the scoping of names look alright. What's with the cryptic error?

Comment: Nevermind. `{:port}` should be `{port:}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Watch the colon. Move it from the front of the port area:

Either

```
data = 'foo {family} {port:} {direction}'.format(
```

Or

```
data = 'foo {family} :{port} {direction}'.format(
```

The results of the two options are:

```
>>> foo(12345, out=True)
'foo ipv4 12345 out'
>>> foo(12345, out=True)
'foo ipv4 :12345 out'
```

Comment: Noted. <pedantic>They're called "colons"</pedantic>. ;-)

Comment: That's not pedantic at all :) Remedied.

Answer (score 0):

`{:port}` should be `{port:}`.